# MVVMCross Custom Cell Binding Based on Item properties

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I see wonderful examples of databinding to templates using MVVMCross.  However, I have complex datasources that sets cell UI types in the GetCell(ios & Android) based on properties of the item in the collection currently being loaded:

```
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = null;
        var item = cellItems [indexPath.Section] [indexPath.Row];
        switch (item.DisplayType) {
        case DetailType.Name:
            cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier + "_name")as NameEditCell;
            if (cell == null) {
                cell = NameEditCell.Create ();
            }
            ((NameEditCell)cell).BindFields (item);
            break;
        case DetailType.Phone:
            cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier + "_phone")as PhoneEditCell;
            if (cell == null) {
                cell = PhoneEditCell.Create ();

            }
            ((PhoneEditCell)cell).BindFields (item);
            break;
        case DetailType.Email:
            cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier + "_email")as EmailEditCell;
            if (cell == null) {
                cell = EmailEditCell.Create ();

            }
            ((EmailEditCell)cell).BindFields (item);
            break;
        case DetailType.Property:
            cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier + "_property")as PropertyEditCell;
            if (cell == null)
                cell = PropertyEditCell.Create ();
            ((PropertyEditCell)cell).BindFields (item);
            break;
        case DetailType.Address:
            cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier + "_address")as AddressEditCell;
            if (cell == null) {
                cell = AddressEditCell.Create ();
            }
            ((AddressEditCell)cell).BindFields (item);
            break;
        }

        return cell;
    }
}
```

How would you accomplish this in MVVMCross with binding or using templates as described in examples posted illustrating binding to lists with templates?

Answer (score 2):

Polymorphic listviews in Android, iOS and Windwos Phone are shown in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/WorkingWithCollections

In iOS, this sample uses a custom data source which switches identifier based on the individual item:

```
        protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath,
                                                              object item)
        {
            NSString cellIdentifier;
            if (item is Kitten)
            {
                cellIdentifier = KittenCellIdentifier;
            }
            else if (item is Dog)
            {
                cellIdentifier = DogCellIdentifier;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Unknown animal of type " + item.GetType().Name);
            }

            return (UITableViewCell) TableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier, indexPath);
        }
```

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/blob/master/WorkingWithCollections/Collections.iOS/Views/Samples/PolymorphicListItemTypesView.cs